# Excel show degree symbol incorrectly

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which allows user to change the temperature unit, there is a dropdown box containing "° C" and "° F" and then I use VBA to do the rest.

The problem is, I have this code:

```
Dim UnitString As String
Set UnitRange = Worksheets("Units of Measure").Cells
UnitString = UnitRange(1, 1)
MsgBox UnitString
```

and it gives me "? C" or "? F"

The next problem, when I call:

```
UnitRange(1, 1) = "° C"
```

I got "ฐ C" in that cell. (ฐ is one of Thai's characters)

These problems broke my sheet's logic, can anyone help me?

Regards,
Sarun

Comment: You are inputting this symbol using alt+0176, yes?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it.

Comment: Just confirming the input method. What language is your sheet set up for?

Comment: I don't know. I got this file from internet and I found this bug, which may be only for me because my computer have all setting in "Regional and Language Options" of the control panel set in Thai.

By the way, the sheet is whole English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to use Unicode within your VBA routines.  For example, here is a simple routine that formats cells to degrees Centigrade :

```
Sub centigrade()
    Const g = "General"
    dq = Chr(34)
    cent = " " & ChrW(8451)
    s = g & dq & cent & dq
    Selection.NumberFormat = s
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial Unicode MS"
End Sub
```